To install open valley flashing, can I use plastic cap nails or must I use a nail gun
I had thought I could nail the valley flashing down with plastic cap nails and rent a nailgun only for the shingles themselves. But I've seen people say they are only for the felt underlayment. I can't depend on being able to do the flashing and the shingles on the same day so would rather not rent a nailgun for the flashing. What do you say? Thanks.

To install a metal valley flashing You should use galvanised nails, a wide plastic cap is not needed a regular flat head is fine.
A nail gun is not required, but as you are nailing through springy sheet metal it can be tricky to drive these nails
using a hammer: you have to hit hard to to go through the metal, but if the point is slightly crooked it will tend to skate putting your fingers at risk.
An automatic center punch could be used to make dents to prevent (or at least reduce) skating.
Nailgun nails can be driven using a hammer, so you could get the nails before hiring the nail gun.

I have nailed very old(1920s) heavy steel roofing.  Do agree it is very hard on the fingers.

Note that the nail heads should be covered by the shingles that overlap the flashing, so that no nail heads are visible.
